# Need to get the attribute type offset of a DWARF DIE

Tags: c, debugging, elf, dwarf

So I'm trying to parse the DWARF file of a program using libdwarf (I have to stick with C for this purposes), I am trying to specifically get the DW_AT_type tag from each DIE. Most of them (I am not sure if all) are offsets, I am trying to find any useful functions to get the values of those tags.

Example:

<2><  286>
        DW_AT_type                  <156>

What I want here is the 156 offset value of the type attribute of that particular DIE.

Do you guys know if there's any function to do this that is offered by the API?

NOTE: I have to stick with C, so please don't recommend any python libraries or parsing of dwarfdumped files. I am just looking for a particular function, but being trying for the last couple of days and cannot find any in the documentation.

Comment: Please give your question a proper title... we ought to be able to know what your question is about by that alone.

Answer (score 7):

As you figured it out, DW_AT_type is a reference to another DIE.

libdwarf provides various functions named dwarf_form* to convert an attribute raw value to a meaningful type. In your case, you are looking for the dwarf_global_formref function.

Since a reference in dwarf is defined as an offset from the start of the debug information to the DIE you are looking for, call dwarf_offdie_b with the reference
of found.

An example code without error checking:

```
// Dwarf_Debug dbg, Dwarf_Die die already initialized
Dwarf_Attribute attr;
Dwarf_Off offset;
Dwarf_Die typedie;
dwarf_attr(die,DW_AT_type,&attr,NULL);
dwarf_global_formref(attr,&offset,NULL);
dwarf_offdie_b(dbg,offset,1,&typedie,NULL);
```

Be sure to check the manual for the exact meaning of each argument.

Comment: Hmm, this seems really interesting, I didn't check out this question until now. What I did was creating another function to recursively go through the entire DIEs until I found the one matching the offset of the DIE that I am looking the type of. Which I think is basically this, the only thing that you are not taking into consideration is that this must be done until finding the correct DIE. Sometimes the second DIE would be of type const and not char for example..

Comment: Sorry for the late answer...
I would argue that the const DIE is part of the type you are trying to find. I agree that the full type of the top symbol is a tree of DIEs. Of course, if what you really want is just char,int,etc you need to parse the type tree...